# JQuery Plugin Structure. Methods with options, Methods, and Options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been attempting to grasp my mind around a good way to structure a plugin so it can accept method calls with options, just method calls, options on init, and init without options.

So far here is what i have.

```
(function($) {
    var settings = {};
    var defaults = {
        args : "default args"
    };
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            if(options) {
                settings = $.extend({},defaults,options);
            }
        },
        test : function(arg) {
            alert("test: " + arg.args);
            alert("args: " + settings.args);
        }
    };
    $.fn.dataTable = function(method) {
        var args = arguments;
        var $this = this;
        return this.each(function() {
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[method].apply( $this, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( $this, args );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin' );
            }  
        });
    };

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tbl").dataTable();
    //$(".tbl").dataTable({ args : "hello world" });
    $(".tbl").dataTable("test",{args:"test args passed"});
    //$(".tbl").dataTable("test");
});
```

however with this I receive

> test: test args passed

and

> args: undefined

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    var defaults = {
        string1 : "hello ",
        string2 : "world!"
    };
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            if(options) {
                $.extend(defaults,options);
            }
            alert(defaults.string1 + defaults.string2);
        },
        test : function(arg) {
            alert("test: " + arg.args);
            alert("args: " + defaults.string1 + defaults.string2);
        }
    };
    $.fn.dataTable = function(method) {
        var args = arguments;
        var $this = this;
        return this.each(function() {
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[method].apply( $this, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( $this, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 0 ) );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin' );
            }  
        });
    };

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tbl").dataTable();
    //$(".tbl").dataTable({ string1 : "foo", string2 : "bar" });
    $(".tbl").dataTable("test",{args:"test args passed"});
    //$(".tbl").dataTable("test");
});
```

Comment: my only fear is that this will have complications if i try to initialize two instances of the plugin on one page. `var $this = this`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but thanks! Also, re: your comment, instead of `.apply($this...)`, using `.apply($(this)...)` at least uses the single element from the `.each()` function.

Comment: Yes, the line must read: `return methods[ method ].apply( $( this ), Array.prototype.slice.call( outerArguments, 1 ));` to apply the function at one specific element per loop, otherwise for example with `$this` being an array of 8 matching divs would result in calling the function 64 times (8 loops x 8 elements per loop). The same in the default `init` section. This means that the `$this` assignation is not needed and can be removed. -I've named `outerArguments` instead of `args`, to make it clean code, but this does not matter for the `$(this)` issue.

Comment: @rlemon: doing with `$(this)` instead of `$this`, I am initing 8 independent instances and works well.